# Uploading youtube video through the API with json using HTTP in a single request

Tags: youtube, http-headers, postman, youtube-api, multipart

I have been trying to upload a Youtube video including a JSON describing the video properties in the form data. I'm using Postman to send a multipart/form-data POST request, but I can't figure out what headers to use or how to use the boundary in the headers.

I have been searching for hours but there is no official documentation for this (specifically for Youtube) and I don't want to use resumable type request because the amount of requests i can do is limited. I have been trying to take advice from this question [How do I upload a video to YouTube via an HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080924/how-do-i-upload-a-video-to-youtube-via-an-http-request) but to no avail...

Comment: "because the amount of requests i can do is limited" - You mean google api limits? Theese two requests will be counted as one video upload.

Comment: The limit is from my side, i can't use the resumable type option.

Comment: Some time ago i tried to find a way to upload a video in one request, but couldn't.